# how to print the sharepoint list item in console window

Tags: sharepoint

Am using this code to print the list item in Console window it print the name but I want to user in this way 
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", item.Name,item.Title,item.Address,item.AssignTo)).Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SPListItem.Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.xml%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property to return items string representation in Xml format.